# Google Cloud Data Fusion failing to access data from another project, even though the access is granted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, access-control, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have enabled the Cloud Data Fusion API and created an instance in project A in BigQuery. Project A will contain our datawarehouse and load and transform data from other projects on BigQuery. When I try to create a pipeline with source BigQuery from project B on table B.X, I get the error *Unable to get details about the BigQuery table:Access Denied:Table B.X. Permission bigquery.tables.get denied on table B.X (or it may not exist)*.
I have given access to the service account related to the instance of Data Fusion (the red box) in project B as
**BigQuery Data Viewer,
BigQuery Metadata Viewer,
BigQuery Read Session User,
BigQuery User,
Browser,
Storage Object Viewer,
Viewer**
[image]

I only need view access on project B to read data and write on project A, so I do not understand why Cloud Data Fusion pipelines would not recognize table X on project B. What could be the issue?

Comment: Is that project A accessing table from project B?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution, I am posting it here for those that might be struggling with the same problem. My service account (the red marked box) was something like `cloud-datafusion-management-sa@project- id.iam.gserviceaccount.com` which according to this link https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/service-accounts#service_account_table, it is deprecated.
So how we fixed it, is by checking the project number in project A (let's say it is 1234566) and add `service-1234566@gcp-sa- datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to project B as **BigQuery Data Viewer, BigQuery Metadata Viewer, BigQuery Read Session User, BigQuery User, Browser, Storage Object Viewer, Viewer**.
So now I can access the tables of project B.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and what worked for me was giving `[DATA FUSION INSTANCE NAME]@[PROJECT ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com` access to **BigQuery Data Viewer, BigQuery Metadata Viewer, BigQuery Read Session User, BigQuery User, Browser, Storage Object Viewer, Viewer, Storage Admin, Storage Object Admin**.

The `[DATA FUSION INSTANCE NAME]` can be found at: https://console.cloud.google.com/data-fusion/locations/-/instances

The `[PROJECT ID]` can be found at: https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard

Giving the service account access can be done at: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam